# create range slider in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a range slider that display the one value, but i wish to display 2 limits i.e min and max, something like a price range slider and then save the min and max value in database, but currently i have only one value.

There are various sliders made through js, but i am wondering can this code be modified to have both max and min values on a single slider ([@fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/learner001/d6nL79e7/))

```
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="range" name="amountRange" min="0" max="20" value="0" oninput="this.form.amountInput.value=this.value" />
        <input type="number" name="amountInput" min="0" max="20" value="0" oninput="this.form.amountRange.value=this.value" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a widget yourself.

Broad idea:

- **Markup and Javscript:**

  1. Have two range inputs inside a container for the widget
  2. Use data attributes on the container to hold the two values e.g. `data-lbound` for storing the lower value and `data-ubound` to store the higher value
  3. Update the data attributes of the container on `input` event of the range inputs
  4. Use these data attributes to retrieve the values any time required for form submission or any other use
- **CSS:**

  1. Use absolute positioning to position the two range inputs on top of each other inside the container
  2. Stylize the range inputs to have their *thumbs* moved a little above so that overlapped range inputs do not prevent their usage
  3. If required, hide the slider/bar/track
  4. Create an `::after` pseudo-element on the container with its `content` property set to the data attributes of the container. This will be used to display the current ranges.
  5. Rest is all about beautifying the ranges inputs.

Here is a small demo that I created. (*Test it out with Chrome or Firefox*) Works with keyboard as well.

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/a1f1k8d0/2/**

**Snippet:**

```css
.multi-range, .multi-range * { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
.multi-range { 
    position: relative; width: 160px; height: 28px; margin: 16px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd; font-family: monospace;
}
.multi-range > hr { position: absolute; width: 100%; top: 50%; }
.multi-range > input[type=range] {
    width: calc(100% - 16px); 
    position: absolute; bottom: 6px; left: 0;
}
.multi-range > input[type=range]:last-of-type { margin-left: 16px; }
.multi-range > input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb { transform: translateY(-18px); }
.multi-range > input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track { -webkit-appearance: none; height: 0px; }
.multi-range > input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb { transform: translateY(-18px); }
.multi-range > input[type=range]::-moz-range-track { -webkit-appearance: none; height: 0px; }
.multi-range > input[type=range]::-ms-thumb { transform: translateY(-18px); }
.multi-range > input[type=range]::-ms-track { -webkit-appearance: none; height: 0px; }
.multi-range::after { 
    content: attr(data-lbound) ' - ' attr(data-ubound); 
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 100%; white-space: nowrap;
    display: block; padding: 0px 4px; margin: -1px 2px;
    height: 26px; width: auto; border: 1px solid #ddd; 
    font-size: 13px; line-height: 26px;
}
```

```html
<div class='multi-range' data-lbound='10' data-ubound='50'>
    <hr />
    <input type='range' 
           min='10' max='45' step='5' value='10' 
           oninput='this.parentNode.dataset.lbound=this.value;'
    />
    <input type='range' 
           min='15' max='50' step='5' value='50' 
           oninput='this.parentNode.dataset.ubound=this.value;'
    />
</div>
```

***Note:*** *The above demo is well, just a demo. It will work perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, but I could not test it in IE/Edge. My feeling is that it will have problems with IE/Edge because the slider thumbs are inline with the track in those browsers. You can further customize and stylize it to work with IE/Edge.*